# Is it possible to determine someones league while playing against them?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is is in any way possible to determine if my opponent is in a higher/lower or same league as myself while I'm actually playing against them in 1vs1 in starcraft 2, or am I forced to check this after the match is over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory if you had a person's user name and number, you could look them up (on the blizzard website).  Unfortunately those numbers are hidden by default so unless you get your opponent to give you his number, I don't see how.

Ultimately I tend to ask my opponents, and I find this works well.  I can probably trust their answers about as well as I can trust them to give their hidden number.

More often than not, I can tell a person's league just by scouting:

- If they have a lot of workers and are using a known build: probably plat/diamond
- If they are doing something weird, or I find a proxy *blank*, probably gold.
- If they don't have more than 13 workers, definitely silver or lower.

These rules aren't hard and fast, but they do tend to explain 90% of my games.

If I'm getting 4 Gate timing push at 6:30 you can bet the guy is in diamond.

Where this breaks down is when you start to get top 10 diamond and then start seeing things like: bunker push, 2 pylon wall in.  And all of a sudden I start sweating...

Comment: What league are you tze?

Comment: @Juan here or on KR?  My usual policy on a ladder reset is to throw my placement games and work my way up the ladder so I get a good cross section of strategies.  The match maker is fairly digressive so usually I quickly end up against Diamond level players.  So while the answer to your question is (usually): Diamond US and Gold KR, that doesn't give you an indication of my skill.  To reference ICCUP rankings I'm probably a C- as zerg, D+ as Terran/Toss... actually that might be generous.

Comment: 'here' is relative, but that answers my curiosity-question :) -- I hadn't thought about *trying* to rank low, it should be fun; the practice matches are absolute fun because both players are inexperienced (in case it wasn't obvious, I just started and I don't have a lot of time to play, so I'm still having fun there).

Comment: @Juan sorry, I live in NA, so "here" means NA to me.  I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the algorithm for advancing from league to league and I intentionally threw games to help with it.  So far the only thing I can verify is that you need some number of losses before it will consider you for moving up (and some number of total games).

Comment: Did you mean moving down? Because that was my next question, suppose you rank high by mere chance, but you lose a lot of matches, how long until it lowers you to a more suitable league?

Comment: Looking them up using their ingame name here is not good enough/reliable? http://sc2ranks.com/

Comment: @PeterK it's semi-reliable if they don't have a common name.  Of course unless you're having someone else look it up it seems like it would be too much of a distraction to alt-tab back and forth between building and looking up.  But maybe that's cause my APM's below 50 :p

Comment: @Juan nope, I mean moving up.  To move up a league you must have a minimum number of losses.  There is also a minimum number of games.

Comment: has that "minimum number of losses" thing been confirmed? I moved up to gold at the end of a 10 game winning streak.

Comment: also, back when i was in silver, several people lied to me about what league they were in, so certainly don't adjust your strategy/paranoia level based on what they say!

Comment: @Peter there is both a minimum number of losses, and minimum number of games.  As a result you can move up on a win, but unless you have enough losses you won't move up.  There were some rather extreme examples of this where players had 60+ wins and less than 7 losses.

Comment: hah! that must have been frustrating...

Comment: @Peter: It's never good to adjust your strategy to anything you haven't scouted in-game (though it's ok to add your off-game knowledge). I can't remember who it was, but in a tournament in the beta some pro played against IdrA, thinking IdrA would go roaches... and got seriously beaten by hydras. Don't assume - scout.

Comment: @Dbemerlin I'll do you one better.  In GSL IdrA went against LotzePrime.  Now the openings for your games are public on the Bnet so if you know your opponent you can practice against their BO.  So IdrA knew Lotze's BO and beat him easily in G1.  Artosis was bragging about this on the stream.  Someone told Lotze and for G2 he did proxy Void Ray.  Now IdrA was so sure Lotze was going his standard 3 Gate/Colossus, that he didn't even scout him. Instead he went 14 hatch/15 pool.  By the time Lotze Void Rays showed up IdrA had only 2 queens and tapped out.

Comment: If you want to, you can watch game 1 here: http://www.gomtv.net/2010gslopens1/vod/1055  You'll see Artosis talking about checking out BOs.  Sadly Game 2 isn't up for free.

Comment: What do you mean by "find a proxy blank"?

Comment: @Jed Proxy Barracks, Proxy DT Shrine, Proxy Hatch, etc

Comment: @tzenes Ok, thanks, that makes more sense. I thought you were saying something about an empty proxy. You might want to say "any type of proxy" instead, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Here is a picture of the only way I know of determining what rank your opponent is before the game starts. Keep an eye out for the color of the boarder around your opponents unit portrait during the vs loading screen before the game starts.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/index.php?title=File:Portrait_Borders.jpg&filetimestamp=20140322032611&